# Statement to get complete table ? In SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In SQL Server, I am trying to get the rows from the two tables where first table is master table and second is child table. like I have a table which contain file extensions with id, and description of extension. second table is having employees who having extension ids from Master table. now i want to get the total master table and if i place where condition for particular employee his extensionid and description.

When I write left outer join it is getting only that particular employee extension details,
my sql statement like this:

```
select * 
from Tbl_File_Extn_M FEM   
left outer join  Tbl_File_Extn_EmpLink_M FEEM on FEM.ExtId = FEEM.ExtId  
where  FEEM.EmpID = '004135'
```

Result is giving only one row, but I need the complete master table and particular employee details can you help me.

Comment: what if you move `where` clause to join condition ?

Comment: no marc, i want all rows from master table with partcular employees extension

Comment: ya sure marc_S i will do that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
select *  
from Tbl_File_Extn_M FEM    
left outer join  Tbl_File_Extn_EmpLink_M FEEM on FEM.ExtId = FEEM.ExtId AND FEEM.EmpID = '004135'
```